# fabrcjs v2 selection breaking changes

Tags: selection, fabricjs2

In the list of breaking changes for fabricjs v2, one of the entries says:

"Click and drag on the canvas creates a rectangular selection. All the bounding boxes intersecting with this rectangle will be selected on mouse up creating a multi selection."

This turns up to be impractical on crowded canvases as it is hard to just select what you want.

Is there a way to only select objects which bounding rectangles are included in (as opposed to intersecting) the selection area?

---

I checked a bit in rc3 and the following mod does what I want:
I know it is brutal...
And I have no means to know if that breaks other things (at least not yet)

at line 11484 in the _collectObjects() function:

```js
//        if (currentObject.intersectsWithRect(selectionX1Y1, selectionX2Y2) ||
//            currentObject.isContainedWithinRect(selectionX1Y1, selectionX2Y2) ||
//            currentObject.containsPoint(selectionX1Y1) ||
//            currentObject.containsPoint(selectionX2Y2)
//        ) {
        if (
            currentObject.isContainedWithinRect(selectionX1Y1, selectionX2Y2) 
        ) {
          group.push(currentObject);

          // only add one object if it's a click
          if (isClick) {
            break;
          }
        }
```